# Unable to get product id (Web Element) in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

As  I am scraping from https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168 my objective is to get all product ids but it can't print

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 
url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
content= soup.find_all('div',class_='col-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-3 mb-2 mb-md-1 mb-lg-4 px-lg-3') 
skechersshoes=[]

for item in content:

    pid=item.select_one('div[data-pid="product"]')
    
    print(pid)
    skechers={
            'productid':pid
            
    }
    skechersshoes.append(skechers)
df = pd.DataFrame(skechersshoes)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('skechers.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: There is too many dependencies for me to debug this for you.  Does the loop execute the expected number of times?  Does item contain the expected data?

Comment: @Allan Wind as updated and highlighted with red mark

Comment: It shows data-pid being a number but you search for data-pid="product"

Answer (score 0):

There're couple of ways how to reach it out:

1.By facilities of selenium find all elements by xpath and class: product:

```
products_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']")
```

and in the loop get 'data-pid' value and put it to the list:

```
skechersshoes = [product.get_attribute('data-pid') for product in products_elements]
```

2.By BeautifulsSoup, set pageSource, then find_all products:

```
products = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "product"})
```

and again, via loop get all 'data-pid'

```
skechersshoes = [_id['data-pid'] for _id in products]
```